# Is there a word in English that refers to proximity in grammar?

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, *here* refers to something that is near by, whereas *there* and refers to something that has some distance to it. Is there a word that describes this in grammar? Another example could be *this* and *that*: *this* implies closeness, and *that* implies distance.

A non-English example could be how - in Spanish - *aquí* / *acá* refer to something close (they are approximate to *here* in English) and *allí* / *ahí* / *allá* refer to something far off (approximate to *there*). Spanish also has *este* and *ese*, which translate literally to *this* and *that*.

Comment: Are you requesting a word that describes how close to grammatically correct a sentence is?

Answer (score 4):

These are *deixis categories*.

*Here* and *there* are examples the [deixis category of place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis#Place).

*This* and *that* fall into the [deixis category of discourse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis#Discourse).

Comment: Yes. And  *this* and *that* exhibit, respectively, *proximal* and *distal* deixis.

Comment: If you find this answer, would you please consider checking the green check mark? This is how we get "paid" for answering the questions.

Answer (score 0):

A clarification on the Spanish example (note, I am not at all fluent in Spanish):

- *aquí* means **here**
- *allí* means **there** (nearby but not quite "here")
- *allá* means **way over there** (farther than nearby)

I can recall my Spanish teacher speaking and gesticulating:

> ¡aquí!  **points to the table he's standing by**,
>   ¡allí!    **points at the middle of the classroom**,
>   ¡allá!   **waves at the back of the room**

In English, we do not have a common word to refer to "way over there."  We just have "there," which means "farther away than here."

See @rajah9's answer for the grammar portion of this question.

Comment: Please use comments or chat to provide clarifications, and only use the Your Answer box to answer the original question.

Comment: @choster, it started that way, but it was too long.  My original skimming of the question was that it was asking about the difference between *allí* and *allá* and if English has a similar pair of terms.  That question better fits the [tag:single-word-requests] tag.  I answered that question even though the question is actually asking for a grammatical construct.